# Uwsgi+Flask+pylibmc: define thread destructor

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, memcached, uwsgi

I have a Flask application which is run behind uwsgi with those settings in an `app.ini` file:

```
...
processes=1
threads=2
...
```

The app is defined in a single file with generic flask structure:

```
@app.route('/endpoint/')
def endpoint():
   ...
```

I'm also using pylibmc for accessing ElastiCache, but given that uwsgi spawns threads as well as processes, and pylibmc.Client is VERY non-threadsafe, I get a lot of errors because of that.

> Of course this requires that you let the pool know when a thread is
>   done with its reserved instance, so therefore `relinquish` must be
>   called before thread exit.

But I don't spawn threads by hand so I have no idea where to define the destructor to call `relinquish` on the pool to avoid dead connections.

The question is: **how do I define thread destructor in a setting where uwsgi is the one creating the threads implicitly?**

Comment: I know your question is 6 years old, but did you ever find a solution to this problem?